# How to check or unCheck the "Select ALL" check box, if any one of the other check boxes are checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Operation No 1:
I have one super check box label as "Select ALL", and 10 other check boxes. if the Select All check box is check , all other checkbox should be check. if Select ALL check box is unchecked the all other should be unchecked.
This working fine

Operation No 2:

In case If all the check boxes are checked, if i uncheck any one check box, the Select ALL check box being unchecked. 
This working fine.

What I want is If 9 check boxes are check, only 10th and Select ALL are unchecked, When I check that 10th check box, the "Select ALL" check box is remaining unchecked state how to make it check if all other check boxes are checked.

Below image, when all check boxes are check.

if I uncheck any one among those 10 check boxes, "Select All" check box become Uncheck that's correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYks4.png)

If I check the Action check box, all the check boxes are checked but "Select ALL" check box remains uncheck, it should be check because all the check boxes are checked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BIf9.png)

I couldn't find how to do, if any one knows please help me.

My code is:

```js
$scope.itemClicked = function($index){
  if($index == 0){
    for(var i=0; i<languagePreference.length; i++){
      languagePreference[i].checked = languagePreference[0].checked;
     }
   }else{
     languagePreference[0].checked = false;
    }
 };
```

```html
<div class="list" ng-controller="LangPrefController">
     <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in languagePreference"
                   ng-model="item.checked"                  
                   ng-click="itemClicked($index)">{{item.text}}
     </ion-checkbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you could do these things:

1. To select/deselect all the `checkboxes`, you can simply loop over the elements and setting all the `checked` *properties* to `true/false`.
2. To select/deselect this checkbox programatically, you can use [**`Array.prototype.every()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method, which returns if all checkboxes are selected or not, if all elements are selected that option will be/keep also selected, otherwise, it will be/keep deselected.

Here's a **demo**:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.languagePreference = [];

    function loadData() {
      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        arr.push({
          "name": "Language " + i
        });
      }
      return arr;
    }

    $scope.languagePreference = loadData();

    $scope.itemClicked = function() {
      $scope.selectedAll = $scope.languagePreference.every(function(item) {
        return item.checked;
      });
    }

    $scope.selectAll = function() {
      $scope.languagePreference.map(function(item) {
        item.checked = $scope.selectedAll;
      });
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in languagePreference">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-click="itemClicked()">{{item.name}}
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="selectAll()"> Select All
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sir u r using Select all in seperate class, but Mine all is coming from single class, can we do that???

Comment: Do you mean the `Select All` option is one item of the `array`??

Comment: yes, all the check box should come from single array?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. it should be like this above. A normal array of items and a custom separated option to select/deselect all.